# biblatex \fullcite in table

Tags: tables, biblatex

I am receiving an error when I try to use `\fullcite{}` in a table. Here is a code showing what I would like to accomplish:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    author = {Abc Def},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Test},
    journal = {Test Journal},
    volume =       {1},
    number =       {1},
    pages =        {1-50}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{12cm} }
    \textsc{My Table} & \\ \hline
    1st row & \fullcite{test}  \\ % ERROR
    2nd row &  something else \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, when I change `\fullcite{test}` to `\cite{test}` or `\textcite{test}`, everything compiles properly. What is the problem here?

Comment: There is conflict between the & as tabular separator and the & used internally by biblatex/ieee-style to delimit an argument. You can avoid the error by putting the cite in braces: `{\fullcite{test}}`.

Comment: You should either put your solution as answer or ask me to answer so that the question gets from the "unanswered list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on Ulrike's comment:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{12cm} }
    \textsc{My Table} & \\ \hline
    1st row & {\fullcite{test}}  \\ 
    2nd row &  something else \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```